# Have a textField input show as a label on a different view?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitextfield, label

Like my question states. I want to have a textField and have a user type something in and press a button and it shows as a label on different view? What would I use to do. Could you give an example in code form. Plus it is going to be like 28 different TextFields?

Answer (score 0):

Set a delegate for your text field. The `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method of the [UITextFieldDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) then allows you to intercept the event that occurs once the text field has finished editing.

Your implementation of `textFieldDidEndEditing:` can then instantiate a `UILabel` (or some other type of view) that contains the text that the user input into the text field.

Answer (score -1):

```
-(IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender{

if (!createViewController) {
                createViewController = [[CreateViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreateViewController" bundle:nil];

            }

            UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
            self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
            [backBarButtonItem release];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:createViewController animated:YES];
}
```

and pass `yourTextfield.text` to `CreateViewController` and assign to `yourLabel.text`
I think it will be helpful to you.